# Android WebView Javascript enabled

Tags: android

activity_main.xml

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

i have this code, but javascript is not working :(

Comment: Well just check if the browser settings have javascript disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've forgot one of the most important ones :

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

Comment: `setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState state)`
"This method was deprecated in API level 18. Plugins will not be supported in future, and should not be used." see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29